# Bootstrap navbar overlaps browser scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

On my wepage, there's a full-height sidebar for the menu (260px width) and there's the rest (100vw - 260px). This latter is the scrollable content and I want the header to stay on top.
The problem is that the scrollbar disappears under the navbar and sometimes causes a flickering effect when opening other pages (it appears for a moment, then disappears behind the navbar).

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100vw - 260px);
  left:260px;
  z-index: 1030;
}

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="sidebar">
     ..menuitems..
   </div>
   <div class="main-panel">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

       </nav>
       <div class="content">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
               ...content...
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure that this scrollbar "belongs" to body element and not some other block element?

Comment: its probably some div scrolling not the body of html

Comment: No, that's the default browser scrollbar

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or Codepen of that ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I'm using a template and I thought someone can come up with an idea who ran to this issue earlier.